# Viber Profile Pictures not showing

Tags: viber

I had viber installed in my Windows phone (Microsoft Lumia 535). And I removed it and installed again. But now I can not see my friend's profile pictures.

I can not see a way to clear cache. I removed viber again and installed. But the issue did not fix. How I can fix this problem?

Comment: Seems no one has any idea. Are there any other sites like viber or Microsoft support to give a help for me?